# Using reportlab in python to create pdf from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, reportlab

I am able to create a report from a data frame that I create using an excel file.

What I am not able to achieve is

a) Have headers on every page
b) Specify column width
c) Wrap text in each cell and adjust the height accordingly.

This is the existing code

```
import pandas as pd
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

# Path to the Excel file
file_path = 'file.xlsx'

# Load the second sheet into a data frame, skipping two rows
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='mainsheet', skiprows=2)

# Columns used for grouping
group_columns = ['Country', 'State', 'City']

grouped_df = df.groupby(group_columns)

# Create the PDF document
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("output.pdf", pagesize=letter)

# Create a list to hold the PDF content
elements = []

# Define the table style
table_style = TableStyle([
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'gray'),
    ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'white'),
    ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'CENTER'),
    ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
    ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 12),
    ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 12),
    ('BACKGROUND', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 'white'),
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, 'gray'),
])

# Iterate over the grouped dataframe
for group_key, group_df in grouped_df:
    # Create a new table for each group
    table_data = [group_df.columns.tolist()] + group_df.values.tolist()
    table = Table(table_data)

    # Set the table style
    table.setStyle(table_style)

    # Autofit column widths
    table.setStyle(TableStyle([('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Helvetica')]))
    
    # Add the group information as a header
    group_info = "Group: " + " / ".join(str(val) for val in group_key)
    header_paragraph = Paragraph(group_info, getSampleStyleSheet()['Heading2'])
    elements.extend([header_paragraph, table])

    # Add a page break after each group
    elements.append(Paragraph("<br/><br/>", getSampleStyleSheet()['Normal']))

# Build the PDF document
doc.build(elements)
```

Can someone help with this?